# Would estimating a mixture model using MLE or EM provide different results?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization

I have built a very hard mixture R (code) using EM-algorithm. My supervisor asked me to repeat the estimation using MLE as it is simpler than EM-algorithm. Building another complex R code will take a very hard time (as I am working with a complex model). My question is, would estimating the same model using MLE and EM-algorithm provide different results? For me, I think they are both useable methods and we can choose the one we think is good for our model? is that correct?

Comment: It seems strange to estimate mixture models without EM and only MLE. How does MLE deal with the latent variable? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @tomka thank you so much for your comment. He asked me to use only Gaussian distribution as it is easy with MLE.

Comment: EM is an algorithm for computing MLE estimate. However, computing MLE is intractable even for gaussian mixture model, and EM only achieves local maximum. If you want to try another method, maybe consider using MCMC sampling.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Thank you so much. Your comment is very helpful.